# CSS Grid колонки разной высоты

Tags: css, css3, css-grid, grid-layout

Как расположить колонки разной высоты друг под другом, при помощи Grid? 
Как показано на изображении.

[image: колонки разной высоты]

Тут пример кода:

```css
.gallery__grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 30px;
}

.gallery__grid-item {
  background: #000;
}

.gallery__grid-item:nth-child(even) {
  height: 150px;
}

.gallery__grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery__grid">
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"><img src="img/gallery/1.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"><img src="img/gallery/2.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"><img src="img/gallery/3.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"><img src="img/gallery/4.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"><img src="img/gallery/5.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"><img src="img/gallery/6.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Высота блоков разная или переменная?

Comment: @AuRoom Здравствуйте. 
Там картинки. 
Соотношение размеров, как в примере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вы уже поняли CSS Grid позволяет генерировать разметку только с прямоугольными элементами. Поэтому чтобы у вас получилось, можно поиграться с `position: relative` и отрицательными `margin`.

Пример (будет работать для любого кол-ва строк с элементами):

```css
.gallery__grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.gallery__grid-item {
  background: orange;
  height: 120px;
}

.gallery__grid-item:nth-child(2) {
  height: 135px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.gallery__grid-item:nth-child(3n + 2) {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}

.gallery__grid-item:nth-last-child(1),
.gallery__grid-item:nth-last-child(3) {
  height: 135px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery__grid">
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"></div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"></div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"></div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"></div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"></div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"></div>
</div>
```

Данный пример будет работать корректно, если у нас 3 столбца и кол-во элементов кратно трём.

Comment: Спасибо! 
Но с картинками у меня что то не получилось выровнять( Сделал так &-item
  &:nth-child(4)
  &:nth-child(6)
   position relative
   top -29.44%

Comment: https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/zRVJox?editors=0100 - получается для каждого блока нужно задавать отступ (отрицательный). А если изображения вообще все разной высоты, то еще и отступ вычислять на глаз) Если я правильно понимаю, то гриды не позволяют управлять блоками разной высоты

Comment: @SkipTyler Я не совсем понимаю что именно у вас не полулось с картинками. Просто картинки должны либо быть разными, либо с какой-то из сторон обрезаться, так как блоки будут разной высоты.

Comment: @SkipTyler Если хотите, добавьте новый вопрос с картинками и объясните как именно должны вести себя блоки в этом случае. Потому что в некоторых случаях CSS Grid может уже не подойти.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, CSS Grid задумывался не для того что бы играться с марджинами, поставьте ваши ячейки в нужные строчки или используйте `grid-areas`.

```css
.gallery__grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100px 40px 100px;
  grid-gap: 30px;
}

.gallery__grid-item {
  background: #000;
}

.gallery__grid-item:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.gallery__grid-item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

.gallery__grid-item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery__grid">
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"><img src="img/gallery/1.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"><img src="img/gallery/2.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"><img src="img/gallery/3.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"><img src="img/gallery/4.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"><img src="img/gallery/5.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item"><img src="img/gallery/6.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Вариант с регионами

```
.gallery__grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 100px 40px 100px;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-areas: "a a a" "b b b" "c c c";
  /* называем регионы */
}

.gallery__grid-item {
  background: #000;
}

.gallery__grid-item:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: 1 / auto / 3 / auto;
  /*grid-area: a / auto / b / auto; тоже самое что и выше*/
}

.gallery__grid-item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: 2 / auto / 4 / auto;
  /*grid-area: b / auto / c / auto; тоже самое что и выше*/
}

.gallery__grid-item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-area: 1 / auto / 3 / auto;
  /*grid-area: a / auto / b / auto; тоже самое что и выше*/
}
```

Comment: Ну у меня картинки там будут. Как мне быть с высотой при адаптивности?

Comment: Все зависит от соотношения сторон картинок. если вы используете уже готовые картинки (соотношение сторон 1:1 ,1:2). Просто укажите grid-template-rows в процентах. А высоту всего  грида укажите в пикселях меняйте в зависимости от устройства. Если картинки случайной высоты/ширины то лучше оставить занижение grid-template-rows в пикселях и менять эти значения на адаптивности. К картинкам width: 100%, height: 100%, object-fit : cover

Comment: соотношение 1:1.2944
Спасибо! Попробую!

Comment: @SkipTyler Вы говорили про `grid-areas`, но так и не применили их в ответе, почему?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov добавил вариант с регионами

Comment: @slowBro Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете также сделать это с помощью очень маленьких строк через свойство `grid-auto-rows`, задавая каждому элементу нужный row span через свойство `griw-row`. Результат:

```css
.gallery__grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

.gallery__grid-item {
  background: orange;
  grid-row: span 24;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 7.5px;
  margin-right: 7.5px;
}

.gallery__grid-item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: span 27;
}

.gallery__grid-item:nth-last-child(2),
.gallery__grid-item:nth-last-child(3) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery__grid">
  <div class="gallery__grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="gallery__grid-item">9</div>
</div>
```

К сожаленью, в данном способе видны два явных минуса:

- Из-за смещения, пятый и шестой, восьмой и девятый и т.д. элементы поменялись местами. Из-за этого пришлось немного менять вёрстку.
- Приходится использовать `margin` вместо `grid-gaps` для задания промежутка между ячейками.