# расположение строк

Tags: css, вёрстка, flexbox

не ищу готового решения, но если его получу буду благодарен , больше за советом здесь. или что я должнен почитать, так вот есть меню ,я хочу узнать : как сделать так чтобы блоки занимали всё свободное пространство по высоте ,именно по высоте.( проще говоря чтобы не было промежутков по высоте, так как соседний блок получает высоту соседа).

```css
.header_desctope_nav_menu_subMenu {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 30px 45px;
  z-index: 3;
}
 .header_desctope_nav_menu_subMenu .column_wraper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
 .header_desctope_nav_menu_subMenu .column_item {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
 .header_desctope_nav_menu_subMenu .column_item_text {
  font: 14px Monstserrat, sans-serif;
  color: #7dc76b;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
 .header_desctope_nav_menu_subMenu .column_item_row {
  list-style: disc;
}
 .header_desctope_nav_menu_subMenu .column_item_row a {
  font: 14px Monstserrat, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_desctope_nav_menu_subMenu">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="column_wraper">
      <div class="column_item">
        <p class="column_item_text">ПВХ плитка</p>
        <ul>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">ПВХ дизайн плитка</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">модульная плитка с замковым соединением</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="column_item">
        <p class="column_item_text">Натуральный линолиум</p>
        <ul>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">спортивный</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">акустический</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#"> токорассеивающий</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#"> общего назначения</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="column_item">
        <p class="column_item_text">Линолеум ПВХ в рулонах</p>
        <ul>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">гомогенный</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">гетерогенный коммерческий</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">полукоммерческий</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="column_item">
        <p class="column_item_text">Спортивный ПВХ линолеум</p>
        <ul>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">толщиной до 4 мм</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">толщиной до 6,5 мм</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">толщиной до 9 мм</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="column_item">
        <p class="column_item_text">Резиновые и каучуковые покрытия
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">общего назначения</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">в рулонах</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">спортивные</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="column_item">
        <p class="column_item_text">Транспортный линолеум</p>
        <ul>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">фактурный</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">противоскользящий</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="column_item">
        <p class="column_item_text">Сценический линолеум</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column_item">
        <p class="column_item_text">Специальные покрытия</p>
        <ul>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">акустические</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">антистатические</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">токорассеивающие</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">токопроводящие</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">для влажных помещений</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="column_item">
        <p class="column_item_text">Сопутствующие товары</p>
        <ul>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">клея</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">смеси</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">грунтовки</a></li>
          <li class="column_item_row"><a href="#">инструменты для укладки</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Или единственное решение это создать 2 колонки?

Comment: мой вопрос и ответ дублируется в этом вопросе : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794163/css-grid-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B